# Jquery PrettyPhoto - Make the close button appear only on hover

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

Can someone please let me know if it is possible, and if so, how to make the close button appear only on hover like the navigation buttons.

Many thanks

```
<div class="pp_pic_holder"> 
<div class="ppt">&nbsp;</div> 
<div class="pp_top"> 
    <div class="pp_left"></div> 
    <div class="pp_middle"></div> 
    <div class="pp_right"></div> 
</div> 
<div class="pp_content_container"> 
    <div class="pp_left"> 
    <div class="pp_right"> 
        <div class="pp_content"> 
            <div class="pp_loaderIcon"></div> 
            <div class="pp_fade"> 
                <a href="#" class="pp_expand" title="Expand the image">Expand</a> 
                <div class="pp_hoverContainer"> 
                    <a class="pp_next" href="#">next</a> 
                    <a class="pp_previous" href="#">previous</a> 
                </div>
                <div id="pp_full_res"></div> 
                <div class="pp_details"> 
                    <div class="pp_nav"> 
                        <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_previous">Previous</a> 
                        <p class="currentTextHolder">0/0</p> 
                        <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_next">Next</a> 
                    </div> 
                    <p class="pp_description"></p> 
                    <div class="pp_social">{pp_social}</div> 
                    <a class="pp_close" href="#">Close</a> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
.pp_close {display:none !important;}

.pp_default:hover .pp_close {display:block !important;}
```